# trying to fix a dereferencing error in java

Tags: java

I have a problem where i'm trying to find the date and time for a specific long value from the "new beginning of the universe", aka jan 1 1970.

I get a "cannot be dereferenced" error when i try to pass my new value to the toString thing.

What i don't get, is that this works for getting a time in millis and displaying it a more readable date/time format, so why not after i do a bunch of math with it?

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Date {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Date mydate1 = new Date(10000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        mydate1.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + mydate1.getMyTime());

    Date mydate2 = new Date(100000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        mydate2.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + mydate2.getMyTime());

    Date mydate3 = new Date(1000000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        mydate3.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + mydate3.getMyTime());

    Date mydate4 = new Date(10000000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        mydate4.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + mydate4.getMyTime());

    Date mydate5 = new Date(100000000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        mydate5.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + mydate5.getMyTime());

    Date mydate6 = new Date(1000000000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        mydate6.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + mydate6.getMyTime());

    /*Date date7 = new Date(10000000000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        date7.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + date7.getTime());

    Date date8 = new Date(100000000000);
    System.out.println("The date and time of " +
        date8.elapse + " from the Unix epoch is " + date8.getTime());*/
}

long elapse;

Date() {
    elapse = 1;
}

Date(long elapseTime) {
    elapse = elapseTime;
}



long getMyTime() {
    //java.util.Date date = new.java.util.Date();
    long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long date = currentMillis + elapse - currentMillis;
    System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Comment: Primitive types don't have methods.

Comment: In the future please show only the code that causes the issue, and the precise error message.

Comment: yes... it says that in my textbook and all over the web.

Comment: It's a bad idea to reuse the class names included in JDK(i.e. Date). The comment in your code looks like you intend to use the java.util.Date as well. Also what do you intend to calculate here: `currentMillis + elapse - currentMillis`? It makes no sense.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj... i'm trying to find the date and time of 10000000 millis for example, from the beginning of the UE.  the only way i can think of to do that is to add the value to currentTimeMillis and then subtract the currentTime -- all of this was an effort to make the toString function work so that i could display the time and date of 1000000 millis in a readable format.

Comment: The point was that you add, then subtract, the same number-a no-op in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `toString()` on a `long` (primitive type) -

```
// System.out.println(date.toString());
System.out.println(date);                 // <-- this would work.
System.out.println(String.valueOf(date)); // <-- this would be assignable to a
                                          //     String, but it prints the 
                                          //     same value as the first example.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in : System.out.println(date.toString())

date is of primitive type long (its not an object of wrapper class Long). Hence the method toString() is not available for 'date'. rather you can simple use :

```
System.out.println(date);
```

If you want to print the formatted Date use the following :

```
Dste d = new Date(date);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

Comment: ok... that makes sense. but wont it simply output a big ugly number and not a nice neat mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: I have added the code that woould take care of that

Comment: @ashape Remember that while `date` may have meaning to you as a date, to Java it is nothing more than a number of primitive type `long`. There's no way for Java to know that your `long` represents a date, hence having to "tell it" as much with something like `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for the help... i know you guys get frustrated by newbies.    the code repair looks like it might work but it generates a bunch of "cannot find symbol" errors and i wouldn't even know what to call those items.

Comment: @ashape It would make more sense if you name your variables to reprsent what they mean eg : long epochTime , Date date...that would make the code more readable.

Comment: @everyone... i'm completely lost, but sincerest thanks for your help.

Comment: @ashape is your issue solved ? If yes then you shuold mark the answer as accepeted so that other people can refer if they have same issue

Answer (score 0):

In

```
long date = currentMillis + elapse - currentMillis;
```

The variable `date` is a primitive (`long`) and not a object. `toString` is a method all java classes inherit from `java.lang.Object` and so will be available in all objects (that are instance of classes). long is just a primitive, primitives do not have methods, they do not inherit from Object either.

So all you need is

```
  System.out.println(date);
```